# Why does polars group_by_rolling corr produce both null and NaN instead of one or the other?

Tags: python, correlation, python-polars

```py
import polars as pl

ts_count_df = pl.DataFrame([pl.Series("ts", [
    1687743109438,
    1687831935720,
    1687958569223,
    1687978376064,
    1688095371395,
    1688213575425,
    1688262561054,
    1688281964195,
    1688362014828,
    1688442925287
]), pl.Series("count", [
    0,
    0,
    19301,
    67,
    0,
    3009,
    1871,
    0,
    95,
    12,
])]).with_columns(
    pl.from_epoch("ts", time_unit="ms")
).sort("ts")

with_corr = ts_count_df.group_by_rolling(index_column="ts", period="3d").agg(
    [pl.corr("count",
             "count").alias("corr"),
     pl.mean("count").alias("avg")])

print(with_corr.head())
```

outputs:

```
┌─────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ ts                      ┆ corr               ┆ avg                │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                ┆ ---                │
│ datetime[ms]            ┆ f64                ┆ f64                │
╞═════════════════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2023-06-26 01:31:49.438 ┆ null               ┆ 0                  │
│ 2023-06-27 02:12:15.720 ┆ NaN                ┆ 0                  │
│ 2023-06-28 13:22:49.223 ┆ 1.0000000000000002 ┆ 6433.666666666667  │
│ 2023-06-28 18:52:56.064 ┆ 1.0000000000000002 ┆ 4842               │
│ 2023-06-30 03:22:51.395 ┆ 1                  ┆ 6456               │
│ 2023-07-01 12:12:55.425 ┆ 1.0000000000000002 ┆ 5594.25            │
│ 2023-07-02 01:49:21.054 ┆ 1                  ┆ 1626.6666666666667 │
│ 2023-07-02 07:12:44.195 ┆ 1                  ┆ 1220               │
│ 2023-07-03 05:26:54.828 ┆ 1                  ┆ 1243.75            │
│ 2023-07-04 03:55:25.287 ┆ 1                  ┆ 997.4              │
└─────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Why are the first two values of corr `null` and `NaN`? I would expect the first two days to be both `NaN` or both `null` not one of each?

Another example:

```py
ts_count_df = pl.DataFrame([pl.Series("ts", [
    1687743109438,
    1687831935720,
    1687958569223,
    1687978376064,
    1688095371395,
    1688213575425,
    1688262561054,
    1688281964195,
    1688362014828,
    1688442925287
]), pl.Series("count_in", [
    15518,
    15518,
    15518,
    15518,
    15524,
    15524,
    15524,
    15524,
    15524,
    15524,
]), pl.Series("count_bo", [
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
    38,
])]).with_columns(
    pl.from_epoch("ts", time_unit="ms")
).sort("ts")

with_corr = ts_count_df.group_by_rolling(index_column="ts", period="3d").agg(
    [pl.corr("count_in",
             "count_bo").alias("corr"),
     pl.mean("count_in").alias("mean_count_in")])
print(with_corr.head(10))
```

outputs:

```
┌─────────────────────────┬──────┬───────────────┐
│ ts                      ┆ corr ┆ mean_count_in │
│ ---                     ┆ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ datetime[ms]            ┆ f64  ┆ f64           │
╞═════════════════════════╪══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2023-06-26 01:31:49.438 ┆ null ┆ 15518         │
│ 2023-06-27 02:12:15.720 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15518         │
│ 2023-06-28 13:22:49.223 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15518         │
│ 2023-06-28 18:52:56.064 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15518         │
│ 2023-06-30 03:22:51.395 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15520         │
│ 2023-07-01 12:12:55.425 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15521         │
│ 2023-07-02 01:49:21.054 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15524         │
│ 2023-07-02 07:12:44.195 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15524         │
│ 2023-07-03 05:26:54.828 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15524         │
│ 2023-07-04 03:55:25.287 ┆ NaN  ┆ 15524         │
└─────────────────────────┴──────┴───────────────┘
```

why does corr is Nan? There are periods with 3 days...
is it same as here: https://saturncloud.io/blog/pandas-corr-returning-nan-too-often-understanding-the-issue-and-finding-the-solution/#2-constant-values-in-the-data
constant values?

Comment: I edited your question to emphasize what I think you're trying to get at. Feel free to revert if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Perhaps a  "simpler" representation is `pl.select(pl.corr(pl.lit([0]), pl.lit([0])))` vs. `pl.select(pl.corr(pl.lit([0, 0]), pl.lit([0, 0])))` - it seems like the `null` may be a "bug"? Maybe this needs to be filed as an issue?

Answer (score 1):

because these values ​​cannot be calculated because there is no data in the "count" column for the first two days. The rolling aggregation process calculates statistics based on data over a specific period. For the first two days, there was not enough data in this period (3 days), so the correlation ("corr") cannot be calculated.

By the end of the first two days, more data had been collected and therefore correlation calculations became possible. Therefore, from the third day onwards the correlation value ("corr") can be calculated and displayed.

Therefore, displaying "null" and "NaN" values ​​for the first two days is expected behavior because the correlation cannot be calculated for these days.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was confused why null,NaN, why not null, null or Nan,Nan